# Separate specific bit in C++

Tags: c++, binary, shift

I am trying to get the only n-bit of an int (4Bytes-32bit) at the fist position (b0)

I am trying this:

```
temp = value << (32-innerIndex);
temp = temp >> 32;
```

where `value` is the integer and `innerIndex` is the position of bit that I want to take.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that you might be doing something wrong?

Comment: You must use `&` to extract a bit.

Comment: @mkrieger1 because sometimes a get negattive values...

Comment: @Devolus can you explain me a bit more?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: If `temp` (promoted if necessary) is a 32-bit type, then `temp >> 32` is __undefined__.

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned int mask = 1 << bitnumber;   // Create a mask from the bitnumber
unsigned int bit = value & mask;     // Use the mask to extract the bit.
bit = bit >> bitnumber;     // Shift the bit to position one.
```

The bits are as follows (assuming bitnumber is 4):

```
value = 0x0000ff80
mask = 0
bitnumber = 4

mask = 0000 0000 0000 0000
value = 0000 0000 1111 1000
mask = (1 << bitnumber)
mask = 0000 0000 0001 0000
bit = value & mask
bit = 0000 0000 0001 0000
bit >>= bitnumber
bit = 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

Or more compact:

```
temp = (value & (1 << innerIndex)) >> innerIndex;
```

Or even more efficient:

```
temp = (value >> innerIndex) & 1;
```

Don't use `signed int`s for that, as that might cause unwanted side-effects.

Bitnumbers are from 0..31.

Comment: A more compact solution would be to just right-shift the desired bit into position 0, and then mask the result with `1`, eg: `temp = (value >> bitnumber) & 0x01;`.  No need for calculating a `mask` at all.  Or, if you do use a `mask`, since the value of any given bit can only be 0 or 1, you could just use `temp = ((value & mask) == mask);` and let the compiler convert the resulting boolean `false`/`true` to an integer `0`/`1`.

Comment: I was using the mask for explanataroy reason.

Comment: If `bitNumber` is 4, the `mask` resulting from `1 << bitNumber` would be `0000 0000 0001 0000`, not `0000 0000 0000 1000`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you are right, I corrected that.